# Python os.listdir и кириллица

Tags: python

Почему `os.listdir()` возвращает список вида: `['#U041a#U0430#U0444#U0435#U0434#U0440#U0430 o#U0431#U0449#U0435#U0439 #U0438',...]`? Понятно, что это из-за кодировки, ведь папки в этой директории на кириллице, но вопрос - как это исправить? Питон 3

Comment: Это не нужно исправлять. Попросту особенность хранения строчек.

Comment: @decube Как быть, если эти строки выводятся пользователю? Нужно их преобразовать в нормальный текст

Comment: целевая платформа какая? винда?
Вообще я очень удивлен, потому что обычно юникод кодируется в виде "\u041a"

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так (вместо обычной строки с путём юникод путя):

```
os.listdir(u'.')
```

Comment: Это не сработало. В обозревателе Windows все символы отображаются нормально, но при сжатии и распаковке WinRar проблема проявлялась в система Linux